# Mysql with magento causing drop in mysql connection

Tags: mysql

What does these errors mean and why does they occur

```
2020-12-11T10:11:48.355887Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356116Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error. 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356132Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356650Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins. 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.356665Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.357957Z 0 [Note] Binlog end 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.364822Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV' 
2020-12-11T10:11:48.366417Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

The following error occured due to magento `setup:upgrade`
As a result the mysql connection keeps dropping for every request (if i refresh page.navigate to other page)

Comment: Looks like broken/unfinished MySQL upgrade. Try to upgrade MySQL separately.

Comment: I didnt upgrade mysql. I upgraded magento setup

Comment: Are you sure that this action does not try to upgrade or reconfigure MySQL?

Comment: yes,It updates db schema not mysql